# Which operators to overload for Python set to function properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, operator-overloading

I am writing a simple container class, the instances of which I would like to store in a `set` and hope that the duplicates are stripped. For example, I can write using `tuple` as a container:

```
in>  set([(1,2),(1,2)])
out> {(1,2)}
```

But if instead I define

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.x > other.x:
            return True
        elif self.x == other.x:
            return self.y >= other.y
        else:
            return False

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.x < other.x:
            return True
        elif self.x == other.x:
            return self.y <= other.y
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

and then try

```
set([Point(1,2), Point(1,2)])
```

I end up with a set of 2 objects instead of 1. Which operators do I need to overload (or what else needs to be done) for `set` to function predictably?

Thank you.

Comment: `set` and `dict` objects rely on the `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods of the objects. You are inheriting the default hash, which essentially hashes by *identity*. Since both your objects are distinct, they hash to separate buckets. You want your `__hash__` and `__eq__` to be consistent. In this case, they are not.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset,

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

According to https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-hashable,

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method).

You've got `__eq__`, so all you need now is `__hash__`. (`__ne__` should also be implemented, or you'll get results where `x == y` doesn't match `not (x != y)`.)

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other)
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return not (self == other)
        return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))


print(set([Point(1,2), Point(1,2)]))
```

Result:

```
set([<__main__.Point object at 0x02F4F090>])
```

For style points, you might also want to implement `__repr__`, so your set object looks nice. Add in `def __repr__(self): return "Point({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)` and your set will display as `set([Point(1, 2)])`.

Comment: NB: Mutating hashable objects can lead to serious trouble.

Comment: @Goyo could you please elaborate? if hash changes in the middle of the life of the object, this assumes sets, dicts and other hash-dependent objects will need to be reassembled, correct?

Comment: @gt6989b it is generally bad to make mutable objects hashable, or at least, to mutate objects that you are going to be putting in dict and set objects.

Comment: I am wondering why `__repr__` is not enough. I tried but set could not remove the duplicate string. What am I missing here?

Comment: @mad_ `__repr__` is totally irrelevant

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and can you explain why? I understand hash could be the way to go but if two strings are same of similar objects then also we should be able get the result. like `set(['a','a'])` will give a single instance of `a`

Comment: `set(['a','a'])` can detect the duplicate "a" because the str type has a `__hash__` method. This doesn't mean the set type converts all objects to string before comparing them.

Comment: @mad_ because it's *completely irrelevant* to how things get hashed into `set` and `dict` objects, that relies solely on `__eq__` and `__hash__`. `__repr__` just controls how they are *represented* when you print them. The objects going into the sets are not strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I figured out I misinterpreted the question. thanks for the info though. cheers